# JQuery AJAX Request Syntax Issue (mixing vanilla JS function)

Tags: javascript, jquery

For someone who knows JQuery pretty well (not me) this should probably be an easy explanation, but when I run my code like this, it works fine:

```
$('input#addStatButton').click( function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '{{action("StatController@store")}}',
      data: $('form#new_stat').serialize(),
    })
    .done(function(refresh) {
      clearStat();
      $.get('{{action("StatController@show", [$game->id])}}', function(data) {
        var newData = $("#statList" , data)
        $( "#statList" ).html( newData );
        //console.log(newData);
      });
    });
  });
```

Notice the position of the 'clearStat()' function. That simply clears a form to prevent a user from submitting it twice. I want this to run as early as possible so that I can ensure that the submit button goes away quickly.

However, when I run it like this, moving it up for that exact reason, nothing below the 'clearStat()' works...

```
$('input#addStatButton').click( function() {
    clearStat();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '{{action("StatController@store")}}',
      data: $('form#new_stat').serialize(),
    })
    .done(function(refresh) {
      $.get('{{action("StatController@show", [$game->id])}}', function(data) {
        var newData = $("#statList" , data)
        $( "#statList" ).html( newData );
        //console.log(newData);
      });
    });
  });
```

And in case it makes a difference, here is the clearStat() function itself:

```
function clearStat() {
  addPlayerToStat(null, null);
  addStatToStat(null);
  document.getElementById("addStatButton").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("playerSelected").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("statSelected").style.display = 'none';
}
```

This confuses me because I don't really know JQuery that well, but I'm sure it is just a silly thing. However, in answering, could you also provide a way that I could run 'clearStat()' BEFORE the AJAX request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `clearStat` is operating on elements in the `form#new_stat` form, you need to call `serialize` **before** you clear the form, so for instance (see `***` commented lines):

```
$('input#addStatButton').click( function() {
  var formdata = $('form#new_stat').serialize(); // ***
  clearStat();                                   // ***
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{{action("StatController@store")}}',
    data: formdata,                              // ***
  })
  .done(function(refresh) {
    $.get('{{action("StatController@show", [$game->id])}}', function(data) {
      var newData = $("#statList" , data)
      $( "#statList" ).html( newData );
      //console.log(newData);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Just because of my lack of knowledge, what is the reason for having to serialize first?

Comment: @Hunter - [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) reads the values from the form. Presumably `addPlayerToStat` and/or `addStatToStat` were clearing the form values.

Comment: Hmm. That is exactly what it does lol. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks!